# Client.send_message sending multiple embeds from sorted json data

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to have a "page forward" feature to my leaderboard that will show numbers 11-20 from the sorted json data. Right now it does show 11-20, but when it sends it, it will send #11 first then it will sent #11 & #12 in another message, then #11, #12, & #13 in another message, etc, etc.

```
client = discord.Client()

try:
    with open("cash.json") as fp:
        cash = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    cash = {}

def save_cash():
    with open("cash.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(cash, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_dollars(user: discord.User, dollars: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in cash:
        cash[id] = {}
    cash[id]["dollars"] = cash[id].get("dollars", 0) + dollars
    print("{} now has {} dollars".format(user.name, cash[id]["dollars"]))
    save_cash()

def get_dollars(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in cash:
        return cash[id].get("dollars", 0)
    return 0

client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!lb cash'):
        cash_leaderboard = sorted(cash, key=lambda x : cash[x].get('dollars', 0), reverse=True)
        msg = ''
        for number, user in enumerate(cash_leaderboard):
            msg += '{0}. <@!{1}> {2} Dollars\n\n'.format(number +1, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0))
            if number == 10:
                break
            else:
                number += 1

            embed = discord.Embed(
            title="TOP BALLER LEADERBOARD\nBallers:",
            color=0x24d7cf,
            description=msg
        )
            embed.set_author(name="BOT", icon_url="")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="")
            embed.set_footer(text="BOT", icon_url="")

        lb_msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
        await client.add_reaction(lb_msg, "⏩")
        lb_wait = await client.wait_for_reaction(emoji="⏩", user=message.author, message=lb_msg, timeout=1800)
        if lb_wait:
            await client.delete_message(lb_msg)
            cash_leaderboard2 = sorted(cash, key=lambda x : cash[x].get('dollars', 0), reverse=True)
            msg2 = ''
            for number, user in enumerate(cash_leaderboard2):
                if number >= 10:
                    msg2 += '{0}. <@!{1}> {2} Dollars\n\n'.format(number +1, user, cash[user].get('dollars', 0))
                    if number == 20:
                        break

                    embed2 = discord.Embed(
                    title="TOP BALLER LEADERBOARD 11-20\nBallers:",
                    color=0x24d7cf,
                    description=msg2
                )
                    embed.set_author(name="BOT", icon_url="")
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url="")
                    embed.set_footer(text="BOT", icon_url="")

                    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed2)
```

Comment: You are already saving the message object to `lb_msg`. Try using `await client.edit_message(lb_msg, embed=embed2`. Also look into adding `asyncio.sleep` to slow down the process a bit to make the message readable as it changes.

Comment: Thanks Benjin, this looks alot better even though it still edits one entry at a time into the embed, at least it doesn't send 10 different messages.

Comment: If you want to add the whole `msg2` instantly then move where you create `embed2` and `await client.edit_message` out of the for loop. This way `msg2` completes inside the loop, it gets added to `embed2` once and the message is edited once.